# How to use cvFitLine Java

Tags: java, opencv

i have the following code:

´

```
        [...]cvCvtColor(subtraction, grayBuffer, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(grayBuffer, grayBuffer, 127, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cvFindContours(grayBuffer, mem, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
        //cvFitLine(Mat(contours[0]),lines,2,0,0.01,0.01);
        cvFitLine(contours, CV_DIST_L2, 2, 0.01, 0.01, line);

        int lefty = (int)((int)(-line[2]*line[1]/line[0])+line[3]);
        int righty = (int) ((int)((grayBuffer.width()-line[2])*line[1]/line[0])+line[3]);
        line(grayBuffer.width()-1,0,righty,lefty); [...]´
```

and this give me a fatal error.

Any one knows how to use fitLine?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a javacv program that uses cvFitLine (written for the Processing language, which provides the setup() and exit() methods):

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.IntPointer;

final int numPoints = 10;
int pt2[] = new int[numPoints*2], x = 0, y = 1;
float testPar[] = new float[4];// to store the results

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    pt2[ i*2 ] = i * 5; pt2[ i*2 + 1 ] = i * 5;
  }

  opencv_core.CvMat point_mat = opencv_core.cvMat(1, numPoints, opencv_core.CV_32SC2, new IntPointer(pt2));
  opencv_imgproc.cvFitLine(point_mat, opencv_imgproc.CV_DIST_HUBER, 0, 0.01, 0.01,testPar);

  for (int i = 0; i < testPar.length; i++) 
    println("i: " + i + ", testPar: " + testPar[i]);
  exit(); 
}
```

the output:

```
i: 0, testPar: 0.70710677
i: 1, testPar: 0.70710677
i: 2, testPar: 22.5
i: 3, testPar: 22.5
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still have same problem. I use cvFindContours before cvFitLine and in that last function apears the following error:

`
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fca032f84d, pid=10268, tid=3640
#
# JRE version: 7.0_13-b20
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [opencv_imgproc231.dll+0xdf84d]  cvFitLine+0x40d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
`